# Russian equivalent of the French expression "C'est plus fort que moi"

Tags: выражения, французский

Go shopping with a broken heart in tow, and you'll wind up buying everything in sight on a spending spree. And this is where you might say "*C'est plus fort que moi* *{It's stronger than me}*":

> Aller faire du shopping, c’est un peu la frénésie d'achats assurée, pour moi et pour l'instant. Déception amoureuse ou pas, je peux pas m'empêcher d'acheter tout ce que je vois ! **C'est plus fort que moi**.

This French expression literally means "It's stronger than me", and is used when you just can't resist the urge/impulse to do something and give in to them despite reason telling you otherwise.

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in Russian?

Comment: is **with broken heart in tow** a kind of an idiom? what does it mean?

Comment: Not so much an established idiom as a tweaked version of the more standard phrase: "with **someone** in tow". "In tow" originates from "a car tow", conveying the figurative notion of someone following you right at your heels. With the use of an inanimate noun "with **a broken heart** in tow" instead, you can picture someone dragging along a heavy heart after a breakup. Anyway, it's just that this was the first phrase that sprang to mind as a short cut to saying: "Go shopping **when you're suffering from a broken heart**, and ...". A way to reduce word count as well as add a dramatised effect.

Comment: i see, thank you for breaking it down, it indeed sounds unusual, although Google retruns a song name *Where do you go with your broken heart in tow?* At first i thought it could have been a typo of **two**, i.e. **broken in two**, but for this reading the word order was non-typical

Answer (score 5):

*Ничего не могу с собой поделать*

Literally, "I can't do anything about me".

> - Вообще это было не очень по-японски, потому что плакать взрослым мужчинам на островах Хоккайдо, Хонсю, Сикоку и Кюсю не положено, но дело зашло так далеко, что Ешитери ничего не мог с собой поделать и на глазах у Гоги, Анты и Маргариты всхлипывал, как маленький ребенок.
> - В 1977 году она обратилась за помощью в благотворительное общество «Самаритяне» и поведала, что совершает медленное самоубийство ― выкуривает ежедневно 180 сигарет, но ничего не может с собой поделать.
> - Я ведь прекрасно знаю, что мое поведение самоубийственно, но ничего не могу с собой поделать.

Answer (score 2):

Мы говорим и кальку:**это сильнее меня**. И "**это выше моих сил**".

Comment: I think that _это выше моих сил_ is more like "I can't take this anymore"

Comment: Словари на академике дают все три версии

Comment: Вы оба правы, по-моему, просто надо добавить немного контекста: "противиться этому/остановиться/взять себя в руки и т.д - выше моих сил".

Answer (score 1):

В некоторых ситуациях эквивалентом этого французского выражения является "охота пуще неволи".

Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что "охота пуще неволи" может употребляться в двух значениях.

Как правило, этот оборот означает, что хочется настолько сильно, что не боишься наказания (неволи). Именно в таком значении этот оборот является аналогом "C'est plus fort que moi."  "Oхота пуще неволи" используется и в смысле "добрая воля эффективнее принуждения" -- но такое употребление встречается куда реже.

Comment: Забавно. Всегда слышал, и употребляю сам, только во втором значении. Как правило, иронически, по отношению к чьим-то не самым разумным действиям. Например, сын-подросток отправляется в жуткую погоду на какую-нибудь там дискотеку допоздна, зная, что назавтра в 7 утра придётся вставать на учёбу..